# Need Remote computer to grab local files

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, powershell-ise

so I'm currently working on our Staging server, which has Admin privileges that I do have. So I've tried the Invoke-Command cmdlet and the Enter-PSSession cmdlet and although these still could help, my main issues is that I'm having trouble getting my remote server (staging server) to reach out to my Local machine and grab some files. This is like the reverse process of what I usually do, which is pushing files from my local machine to a remote server, it's just usually not one with Admin privileges. But since I've been using Invoke and Enter-PSSession, it's like I'm technically remoted into that server using PowerShell, so I would like the Staging server to go out and grab files from my local machine if possible. And just to be clear, I have used another script on this server, so I'm sure its just my inexperience at this point. Below is the script I'm using.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName StagingServer -Credential AdminUser

### Location of starting directory ###
    $_SourcePath = "\\LocalMachine\C$\Deployment\Files" 

### Location where files will be copied to ###
    $_DestinationPath = "C:\Staging\DeployHere"

Get-ChildItem -recurse ($_SourcePath) | Copy-Item -Destination ($_DestinationPath) -PassThru
```

Have Also used:

```
# Set Up Credentials. PSCredentials is an object that stores your username and an encrypted version of your password.
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $env:Password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Managment.Automation.PSCredential $env:Username,$password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName StagingServer -credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
   ### Location of starting directly ###
    $_SourcePath = "\\LocalMachine\C$\Deployment\Files" 

### Location where files will be copied to ###
    $_DestinationPath = "C:\Staging\DeployHere"

Copy-Item ($_SourcePath) -Destination ($_DestinationPath)
}
```

Sorry for long post. And again, I could just be missing a step or messing up entirely. I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: [1] i think `Enter-PSSession` is for _interactive_ use ... and that aint what you are doing. [*grin*] ///// [2] what you describe sounds like the usual `double hop` problem. have you checked that? ///// [3] what errors are you getting? please add the FULL text of the error to your Question & wrap it in code formatting to make it easy to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly easier approach to copy remote files to local machine from local machine:

```
net use \\10.11.12.13\RemoteFolder /user:pc\user myPassword
robocopy \\10.11.12.13\RemoteFolder C:\LocalFolder /Copy /E /R:0 /W:0
```

Flags:

/Copy - Copy

/E - Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders.

More Flags here: https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

R:0 - Number of Retries on failed copies - default is 1 million.
W:0 - Wait time between retries - default is 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but your answer really helped me with my issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Entering PSSession you can create it and store it in variable.

```
$StagingSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName StagingServer -Credential AdminUser
```

Then you can use `Copy-Item` with argument `-ToSession` (or `-FromSession`) to copy items between your local machine and that session:

```
$SourcePath = "C:\Deployment\Files" 
$DestinationPath = "C:\Staging\DeployHere"

Copy-Item -Path "$SourcePath\*" -Destination $DestinationPath -Recurse -ToSession $_StagingSession
```